Docker Image for Torchvsion and Torchaudio with FFmpeg with nvidia headers
I'm trying to perform GPU video encoding/decoding using PyTorch. This means compiling FFmpeg from source along with Nvidia codec headers.
Currently, my docker image looks like this:
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:24.06-py3

RUN apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends ca-certificates expat libgomp1 && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get clean -y

RUN apt-get install -y bash \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    git-core \
    libass-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libgnutls28-dev \
    libmp3lame-dev \
    libnuma1 \
    libnuma-dev \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libtool \
    libva-dev \
    libvdpau-dev \
    libvorbis-dev \
    libxcb1-dev \
    libxcb-shm0-dev \
    libxcb-xfixes0-dev \
    libc6 \
    libc6-dev \
    meson \
    ninja-build \
    pkg-config \
    texinfo \
    unzip \
    wget \
    yasm \
    zlib1g-dev && \
    apt-get -yqq update

# Miniconda
COPY .devcontainer/env.yml .

RUN mkdir -p ~/miniconda3 && \
    wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh && \
    bash ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p ~/miniconda3 && \
    rm -rf ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh && \
    ~/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash && \
    ~/miniconda3/bin/conda init zsh && \
    ~/miniconda3/bin/conda env update --file env.yml

# FFMPEG
RUN git clone https://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git && \
    cd nv-codec-headers && \
    make install

RUN git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg/ && \
    cd ffmpeg && \
    ./configure \
    --prefix="$CONDA_PREFIX"\
    --enable-nonfree \
    --enable-cuda-nvcc \
    --enable-libnpp \
    --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include \
    --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 \
    --disable-static \
    --enable-shared && \
    make -k -j 8 && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

The env.yml contains the following:
name: base
channels:
  - pytorch
  - nvidia
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pytorch=2.3.1=py3.12_cuda12.1_cudnn8.9.2_0
  - torchvision=0.18.1=py312_cu121
  - torchaudio=2.3.1=py312_cu121
  - pytorch-cuda=12.1=ha16c6d3_5

To test the image, I'm running:
import torchvision
from torchaudio.utils import ffmpeg_utils

print("Library versions:")
print(ffmpeg_utils.get_versions())
print("\nBuild config:")
print(ffmpeg_utils.get_build_config())
print("\nDecoders:")
print([k for k in ffmpeg_utils.get_video_decoders().keys() if "cuvid" in k])
print("\nEncoders:")
print([k for k in ffmpeg_utils.get_video_encoders().keys() if "nvenc" in k])

torchvision.set_video_backend('cuda')

I've also created this repo so that other people will be able to just run this image once its problems get solved.
What is going on is that outside the Conda environment, FFmpeg is configured as expected. But inside it, I'm getting the folowing error:
libopenh264.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

By following this comment on a torchvision issue, I was able to make ffprobe -hide_banner -decoders | grep h264 and ffmpeg -hide_banner -encoders | grep 264 yield the expected outputs, as shown in torchaudio's doc, inside the Conda environment. But then torchaudio wasn't able to find FFmpeg.
I'm new to the whole ecosystem (linux, docker and torch), and would appreciate it if someone could help me build this image, as I think that this should actually be officially provided by torch.

This question is similar to: ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libopenh264.so.5. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@talonmies I'm using recent versions of both Python and FFmpeg, not the ones from that question. In my container I didn't even create a new env, I'm just using the base one. I believe that the solution has to do with making Conda access the FFmpeg version that was built from source, that's why I've linked this issue.
